# Does "NOT NULL" prevent rowid aliasing?

Tags: sqlite, rowid

Usually, when Sqlite encounters an `integer primary key` statement, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE [T] (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [...]);
```

then the `id` column will be an alias for the *rowid* column, which is Sqlite's internal ID column.

However, when appending `not null` to

```
CREATE TABLE [T] (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, [...]);
```

is aliasing still activated?

`NOT NULL` should not affect the semantic properties of the table, but the rules for aliasing are quite strict (e.g. it won't accept `int` instead of `integer`), so maybe this slight change will already prevent aliasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid),

> if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid.

"NOT NULL" is not part of the type but is a (superfluous) column constraint, so this will still be the rowid.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Sqlite details - Are you sure that "not null" is not part of the _type_? Is it rather like a constraint (in this case a useless one) placed on the column?

Comment: That's what I said. And it's what the documentation says (see `column-def`).